# SQL Return all rows if admin, otherwise return user records

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, filter, where-clause

When using `SQL` *DataSource*, I want to return the record essentially tied to the currently logged in *user*.  I can do this, just fine.

But, when that logged in user is tagged as 'ADMIN' in the user table, I want to return all rows.

**Fields**:

```
Name  
Address  
databaseid  
IsAdmin
```

ASP.net page sends `@databaseid`

SQL server returns `Name` and `Address` for `@databaseid` user only.  Perfect!

but I want to return everything in the table if `IsAdmin = 1` for that given databaseuserid.

I am using a SP to return records.  Basically ignore the filter.

Comment: You want to return all records if admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you modify the stored proc?  If so, then change the select stmt:

```
SELECT Name, Address, databaseid, IsAdmin
FROM YourTableName
WHERE databaseid = @databaseid
      OR 1 = (SELECT IsAdmin 
              FROM YourTableName
              WHERE databaseid = @databaseid);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  Works perfectly!  I knew I needed to make something equal to something else... but did not conside a sub-select.